# Intellij Typescript error for interface: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifie

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, syntax, interface

I'm trying to perform a simple test of an interface.
The code is as follows:

```
interface TestInterface {
    id: number;
    text: string;
}

const testInterfaceImplementation: TestInterface = {
    id: 1,
    text: 'sample text'
};

console.log(testInterfaceImplementation.text);
```

When I run this code with Node.js configuration I get this error:

```
interface TestInterface {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

When I run the code without this interface it works fine:

```
const testInterfaceImplementation = {
    id: 1,
    text: 'sample text'
};

console.log(testInterfaceImplementation.text);
```

What is the problem? I've also tried to move the interface to a different .ts file but the error still occurs.

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

[run_configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZrDc.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can't run the Typescript code by passing it to **Node.js** directly, **Node.js** doesn't provide native support for executing Typescript. The code has to be either compiled on-the-fly or precompiled. here are some recipes:

*To run a selected TypeScript file using ts-node*:

- Install [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) using `npm i ts-node`.
- Create a new **Node.js** run/debug configuration.
- Add `--require ts-node/register` to the **Node parameters** field.
- In the **JavaScript file** field add `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$`.
- Save configuration.
- Use it to run (or debug) a file that is currently opened in the editor or selected in the **Project** view. You can do that using the icons on the navigation bar or **Run...** action.

If you need to pass any additional parameters to ts-node (e.g. `--project tsconfig.json`), you can add them to the **Application parameters** field in the run/debug configuration.

*To compile app with TypeScript and run a selected TypeScript file*

- Create a **Node.js** run/debug configuration.
- In the **Before Launch** section, click **Add** and select **Compile TypeScript**.
- Select `tsconfig.json`.
- In the **JavaScript file** field you need to select the path to the compiled `.js` file.
- If a compiled JavaScript lives next to its source, add `$FileRelativeDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js`
- If files are saved in an output folder (preserving the folder structure), add the folder name before the pattern, e.g. `build/$FileRelativeDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js`
- Save configuration.
- Use it to run (or debug) a file that is currently opened in the editor or selected in the **Project** view.